# Setting WebSphere MQ RFH2 header using Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I would like to put a message to mq with rfh2 header along with jms and usr folder. As a starting point checked this [link](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=21151) and came up with the code below. However after putting the message using the below code, I got a MQ error code'2142'(stands for incorrect header values). Could some one help on this. Also how do i modify the code to include jms and usr contents?

```
pubCommand = "<psc><Command>Publish</Command><Topic>Stock</Topic>" + 

"<QMgrName>QFLEXT1</QMgrName><QName>QFLEXT1.A</QName></psc>"; 

int folderLength = pubCommand.length(); 
MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
//sendmsg.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
sendmsg.format = MQC.MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2; // Msg Format
sendmsg.feedback = MQC.MQFB_NONE;
sendmsg.messageType = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
sendmsg.replyToQueueName = "MY.TEST.Q";
sendmsg.replyToQueueManagerName = qManager;
sendmsg.writeString(MQC.MQRFH_STRUC_ID); // StrucId 
sendmsg.writeInt4(MQC.MQRFH_VERSION_2); // Version 
sendmsg.writeInt4(MQC.MQRFH_STRUC_LENGTH_FIXED_2 + folderLength + 4); 
sendmsg.writeInt4(MQC.MQENC_NATIVE); // Encoding 
sendmsg.writeInt4(MQC.MQCCSI_DEFAULT); // CodedCharacterSetId 
sendmsg.writeString(MQC.MQFMT_NONE); // Format (content) 
sendmsg.writeInt4(MQC.MQRFH_NO_FLAGS); // Flags 
sendmsg.writeInt4(1208); // NameValueCCSID = UTF-8 
sendmsg.writeInt4(folderLength); 
sendmsg.writeString(pubCommand);
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // accept the defaults, same
// as MQPMO_DEFAULT constant

String line = "test message";
sendmsg.clearMessage();
sendmsg.messageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
sendmsg.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
sendmsg.writeString(line);

// put the message on the queue
queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
```

Comment: Could you clarify why an RFH2 is being created step-by-step. It looks to be a standard publish request... why not use JMS?

Comment: Can I get a sample using JMS?

Comment: There are a large number of JMS samples around - including in the samples or tools directory of the mq installation.

Can you say why you want to create and RFH2 pease?

Comment: The provider expects RFH header with a usr folder along with mcd text. I would like to use java to achieve this..

Answer (score 1):

The ***correct*** answer is that the provider consuming the messages should be using a modern, supported version of WebSphere MQ.  In any current version, the consumer of a message can specify whether they want to see RFH2 headers or message properties.  It doesn't matter which approach the producer of the messages uses, MQ does the necessary conversion.

But if you must do this the hard way, please consider the following:

```
// many lines to prepare the message body are executed here    
String line = "test message";
sendmsg.clearMessage();
// WTF??  ^^^^^^^^^^  Doesn't this wipe out the RFH2 headers you just added?
//                    Any reason NOT to expect incorrect header values error?
sendmsg.writeString(line);
queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
```

According to the [clearMessage page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q034920_.htm?lang=en) in the Knowledge Center "*This method clears the data buffer portion of the MQMessage object. Any Message Data in the data buffer is lost, because MessageLength, DataLength, and DataOffset are all set to zero.*"

So by the time you get around to writing "test message" into the message body, all the RFH2 headers you just added are gone and the message length reset to zero.  Considering that there are no RFH2 headers for the QMgr to parse, the error received seems appropriate.

Regarding the ability for the message consumer to have MQ provide the RFH2 headers, please see: [PROPCTL queue options](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008230_.htm?lang=en) in the MQ Knowledge center, and in particular the `FORCE` option.